# How to position the second image out of 3 in the center of div with overflow hidden on load

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, css-position

I'm making a carousel using vue.js. I have a div with overflow hidden and 3 images. On loading, they should take 25%, 50% and 25% of the div respectively. How can I position them? For now, I use scrollLeft on the mounted hook. But every time the page is loaded, it just jumps. Is it possible to do it with plain CSS, without any jumps?

```html
<div class="flex" style="height:400px;">
  <div class="left" id="left-button" @click="swipeLeft">
    <font-awesome-icon icon="chevron-left" class="silver" />
  </div>
  <div class="flex pt-1 pb-1 lg:px-0 mx-auto relative" ref="titles" id="titles">
    <div v-for="post of posts.value" v-bind:key="post.id" class="relative">
      <BannerPageComponent v-bind:post="post.joke" @moreInfo="showMoreInfo" v-bind:isArticleClicked="activeIndex" v-bind:post_key="post.id" :style="cssVars" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="right" id="right-button" @click="swipeRight">
    <font-awesome-icon icon="chevron-right" class="silver" />
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
 document.onreadystatechange = () => {
  if (document.readyState == "complete") {
    const content = this.$refs.titles;
    var scrollPixels = this.window_width / 4;
    content.scrollLeft = scrollPixels;
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: I updated my question by adding the code